# Is it possible to whitelist a browser access point in TeamViewer 7?

Tags: networking, firefox, browser, teamviewer

I have TeamViewer 7 configured on several machines utilizing whitelist only access. Is there a way that I can allow whitelist access from the browser portal or do I have to download the client on every machine and whitelist the specific client. I use Firefox if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to have a teamviewer ID to key off of.

Comment: And is there no way to assign one either via an addon or cookie to a browser like Firefox?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge.